# delegation jquery on custom event

Tags: jquery, ajax, tipsy

**this my custom event delegation**

```
 $(".main_cont").delegate(".live-tipsy-3", "tipsy", function(){
    $('.live-tipsy-3').tipsy(
     {
         delayIn: 100,      // delay before showing tooltip (ms)
         delayOut: 300,     // delay before hiding tooltip (ms)
         fade: true,     // fade tooltips in/out?
         gravity: 'w',    // gravity
         html: true,     // is tooltip content HTML?
         offset: 10,       // pixel offset of tooltip from element
         opacity: 0.8,    // opacity of tooltip
         title: 'title',  // attribute/callback containing tooltip text
        trigger: 'hover' // how tooltip is triggered - hover | focus | manual
     });    
 });
```

can I run this event without call to `this`

```
 $(".live-tipsy-3").trigger("tipsy");
```

- I need it because after ajax request this custom event not working
- Any ideas